# Does azure VM disk contain information about the subscription?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, forensics, subscription

I'm creating Azure VM with a single drive (IS drive) and creating an image (EO1) of the drive for some testing I am doing. I need to share the image with the client. Will the image contain any information about the subscription?

the VMs are Windows server and windows, the VM is not in network or Azure AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not contain subscription information.